# Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.cli.VaultFsApp

Tags: windows, git, bash, aem

We use VLT and GIT for our AEM site development.

I prefer the branch notifications and color coding etc. of GIT Bash,
to the standard output.

I use both from within ConEmu, and I have added Clink, 
and that is somewhat better, but not as nice as GIT Bash.

Using the regular console I'm able to access VLT,
but when using the GIT Bash console, I get the following error.

"Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.cli.VaultFsApp"

So it seems that there is a path that is not being found,
but running env|grep PATH shows the correct info.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try an older version of vault like 2.4.40.

Answer (score 0):

The shell's "PATH" isn't the problem.

You need to fix the Java "CLASSPATH".

You haven't specified your OS (Windows? Linux?  Other?)

And I'm not sure exactly which program in the mix is using "org.apache.jackgrabbit.vault.cli".  It certainly isn't Git BASH - it sounds like VLT is the guy who needs you to add Apache Jackrabbit to its Java CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Sorry about the lack of OS. I'm running Windows 7-64bit. The reason I was assuming that it was an issue with GIT Bash, is due to the fact that it runs fine from the default shell. I will look into adding the CLASSPATH to VLT.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in Windows 10 by running the command in `cmd`, rather than in `git bash`